# How to set the bg color of body without touching the header?

Tags: html, css

Every time I put some bg code to body it will affect the header. I want to put a different bg color to header and body, but I can't fix it.

```css
#wrapper{
    max-width:auto;
    margin: 80px 100px 65px 80px;
    background-color: #202020;
    padding: 0px;
}

header{
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<div class ="logo"><a href ="#"><img src ="logo.jpg"></a></div>
<div class ="logo1"><a href="#"><img src ="logo2.jpg"></a></div>
<h1>SBCA</h1>
<h2>SKILLED COMMUNICATOR ║ LIFELONG LEARNER ║ VALUES-ORIENTED CITIZEN ║ SERVANT LEADER</h2>
<h3>Saint Bernadette College of Alabang</h3>
</header>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have a starting header tag in your html.

Comment: structure your HTML code properly

Comment: i forgot the opening header in the post but in my code it's in there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the opening `<header>` tag. Replace your HTML with this and you should be fine:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class ="logo"><a href ="#"><img src ="logo.jpg"></a></div>
  <div class ="logo1"><a href="#"><img src ="logo2.jpg"></a></div>
  <header>
    <h1>SBCA</h1>
    <h2>SKILLED COMMUNICATOR ║ LIFELONG LEARNER ║ VALUES-ORIENTED CITIZEN ║ SERVANT LEADER</h2>
    <h3>Saint Bernadette College of Alabang</h3>
  </header>
</div>
```

(assuming you want `h1`,`h2` and `h3` in the header)

Also try to indent your code properly, it helps a lot with finding mistakes like this!

Comment: i forgot the opening header in the post but in my code it's in there, and h1 h2 h3 are on the header.

Comment: @Azelae Then there's no issue left. It works: https://jsfiddle.net/fnzu7y5c/

Comment: take a look with my code i'm frustrated. https://jsfiddle.net/xgab1123/bd2kqj39/

Comment: @Azelae That's because your header is taking up the full space of the #wrapper. If you add `padding: 5px;` to #wrapper you will see your background colour is there, the header is just on top of it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see here, it is because you have all your header content wrapped in the "wrapper" div, and you're trying to assign a different color to both. What you need to do is style the outside of the header. You can do this by adding a background color to the body.

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 80px 100px 65px 80px;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo1">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo2.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <h1>SBCA</h1>
    <h2>SKILLED COMMUNICATOR ║ LIFELONG LEARNER ║ VALUES-ORIENTED CITIZEN ║ SERVANT LEADER</h2>

    <h3>Saint Bernadette College of Alabang</h3>
  </div>
</header>
```